# Vps ovh server configuration

Tags: node.js, git, server, vps

i am using ovh vps to deploy my nodejs application , i installed Git , nodejs, angular cli , npm , but in the last step when  i type : node server.js & it show me this error :

```html
 ` root@vps769904:~# internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;`
    

    `Error: Cannot find module '/root/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)`
```

can anyone help me please !

[image]

Comment: You're not in the right folder that contains your script. Either use `cd` beforehand or run node with the full path to your script.

Comment: @Alejandro i use cd to access to the path of node files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was : ngserve --url of my server port 4200 ! it works good !